# Assignment of char array to struct with type casting

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm working on my C program code to allocate memory without using `malloc()`. My friend was using a linked list to manage memory, and I do it on this example but I don't know how this type of assignment works in function `memory_init()`.

Here's the main of the example test:

```
#include <string.h> 
int main() {   
  char region[50];   
  memory_init(region, 50);   
  char* pointer = (char*) memory_alloc(10);    
  if (pointer)     memset(pointer, 0, 10);   
  if (pointer)     memory_free(pointer);   
  return 0;
}
```

and there's function `memory_init()`:

```
void memory_init(void *ptr, unsigned size) {    

    struct metadata *first;
    first=(struct metadata*)ptr;
    first->next=NULL;
    first->prev=NULL;
    if (size > sizeof(struct metadata)) first->value=(size - sizeof(struct metadata));
    else first->value=0;
    first->boo=-1;
    zac=first;
}
```

and there's also used struct:

```
struct metadata{        
    short boo;      // if -1 free, if 1 memory used
    unsigned value; //size of memory block
    struct metadata *next; 
    struct metadata *prev;  
};
```

So I don't know how this part of the code works:

```
first=(struct metadata*)ptr;
```

> At what I see it it takes a char array sent to the function and retypes it to
>   a struct and assigns it, but I don't know how assignment like that works?
>   Does it assign a memory address or what because I don't take how I can retype
>   char to a struct. Basically I would like to know what happens there.

Comment: Note, since you're basically using a `char` array for generic memory allocation, you are going to want to ensure that memory is aligned. Other data types (like `int`, `short`, etc) have different alignment rules than `char` so your program might crash if it tries to access parts of `region` as a `short` (like in `struct metadata.boo` for example). Of course, this bug might only manifest itself when you modify some unrelated code that messes with how the compile allocates stack space, so to avoid it entirely, declare the variable like so: `char region [50] __attribute__((aligned(8));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have memory; each byte of the memory has an address.

Initially, you have `void *ptr`, which holds an address to some byte in memory.

When you do `first=(struct metadata*)ptr;` you tell the compiler, that from now I threat memory under `ptr` as if this memory holds `struct metadata`, and you use `first` to access that memory.

Think about it as mapping data layout defined by `struct metadata` to some raw memory region.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking, but "ptr" is a void pointer and "first" is a pointer to the "metadata" struct. So "(struct metadata*)" is used as a cast.